# PHP Warning causing sql timeouts?

Tags: php

I got a whole heap of (foreach()) warnings on my server log. Could they be causing sql timeout on my db via a sql connection leak?

I'm not entirely sure how to resolve the problem but i read that i need to add this bit of code:

```
if (is_array($values) || is_object($values))
{
    foreach ($values as $value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

...into my .php but dont really know where to add it or why? sorry noob here again.

Here's my code section for: PHP Warning:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /hermes/bosnacweb03/bosnacweb03aa/b1245/ipg.tinsflowershop/panga/classes/ImageType.php
>   on line 148

(Line 148 starts - **foreach ($results as $result) {**)

```
   /**
     * Finds image type definition by name and type
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $type
     */
    public static function getByNameNType($name, $type = null, $order = 0)
    {
        static $is_passed = false;

        if (!isset(self::$images_types_name_cache[$name.'_'.$type.'_'.$order]) && !$is_passed) {
            $results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_type`');

            $types = array('products', 'categories', 'manufacturers', 'suppliers', 'scenes', 'stores');
            $total = count($types);

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                foreach ($result as $value) {
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; ++$i) {
                        self::$images_types_name_cache[$result['name'].'_'.$types[$i].'_'.$value] = $result;
                    }
                }
            }

            $is_passed = true;
        }
```

I assume that all the warnings on my log are the same issue?  eg:

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /hermes/bosnacweb03/bosnacweb03aa/b1245/ipg.tinsflowershop/panga/classes/Category.php
>   on line 594

Comment: you are not checking if array is not empty. you are just checking it is array or object. so there is nothing to loop through

Comment: try this `if (!empty($values) && (is_array($values) || is_object($values)))`

Comment: thanks for your help!

do i add it before the foreach section?

Comment: you can just replace this line `if (is_array($values) || is_object($values))` with the one i provided. nothing else needs to change

Comment: and add it under - public static function getByNameNType($name, $type = null, $order = 0) ?  Thanks so much again

Comment: sorry, I got the wrong line. `if (!empty($results) {foreach ($results as $result) {..}}`

Comment: @ksoni Looping an empty array is perfectly safe and won't generate any wornings (it's effectively a no-op).  You only get that warning if you try to loop something that isn't an array or an iterable object.

Comment: I don't know what Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS() does specifically (I do know you're depending on a singleton which is bad practice, but outside of the scope of this question), but I suspect it returns an array if there is a result and returns something else if there isn't.  It's usually better to always return what you promise to return.  This means that if there's no results executeS() should either return an empty array (if no results isn't a fatal situation) or throw an exception (if no results means you can't continue)

Comment: @GordonM Thanks, you are correct. I think then this should work `if (is_array($results) || is_object($results)) {{foreach ($results as $result) {..}}}` but ideally as GordonM said the method should at-least return empty array.

Comment: On this link http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices#DBclassbestpractices-executeS() if my guess is right it is returning false possibly when it does not have any records. `if ($results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql))
    foreach ($results as $row)`

Comment: It does return false as per the source code on this link https://github.com/pal/prestashop/blob/master/classes/MySQL.php so this should be suffice `if ($results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql)) {{foreach ($results as $result) {..}} }`